How to resolve "Passing argument of non-sendable type 'NSItemProvider' outside of main actor-isolated context may introduce data races"?
Currently, I am getting
Passing argument of non-sendable type 'NSItemProvider' outside of main actor-isolated context may introduce data races

at line
if let url = try await itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.url.identifier, options: nil) as? NSURL {

and line
let text = try await itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.text.identifier, options: nil) as? String

Do you have any idea how I can resolve such?
Here is the code snippet
private func handleIncomingURL(itemProvider: NSItemProvider) async -> String? {
    do {
        if let url = try await itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.url.identifier, options: nil) as? NSURL {
            
            if let urlString = url.absoluteString?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines), ShareViewController.isValidWebsiteURL(urlString) {
                return urlString
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // Handle errors appropriately here
        print("Error handling incoming URL: \(error)")
    }
    
    return nil
}

private func handleIncomingText(itemProvider: NSItemProvider) async -> String? {
    do {
        let text = try await itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.text.identifier, options: nil) as? String
        
        if let text = text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
            do {
                let detector = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
                let matches = detector.matches(
                    in: text,
                    options: [],
                    range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count)
                )

                for match in matches {
                    if let range = Range(match.range, in: text) {
                        
                        let url = String(text[range]).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
                        
                        if ShareViewController.isValidWebsiteURL(url) {
                            return url
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch let error {
                print("Do-Try Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    } catch {
        // Handle errors appropriately here
        print("Error handling incoming text: \(error)")
    }
    
    return nil
}

Thank you.

https://www.avanderlee.com/concurrency/preconcurrency-checking-swift/

WWDC24: Migrate your app to Swift 6 | Apple
you can check Swift 6 concurrency videos to handle it. First option is adding nonisolated to your function.
nonisolated
    private func handleIncomingURL(itemProvider: NSItemProvider) async -> String?  

While you are adding nonisolated, if you need to implement your actions inside Main thread don't forget to add @MainActor.
 Task { @MainActor in
                
            }

But Swift 6 language mode documents will give you more thoughts about this topic.
